# Android - Trying to open a row from SQLite into multiples fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, swipe

I want to set the text of some EditTexts after clicking on an item of a list.

The activity:
- CadPersonActivity

And three fragments, each one having fields:
- FragmentPersonId
- FragmentPersonAddress
- FragmentPersonPhones

However those EditTexts insist on not showing what I expect.
There's no error, but blank fields.

I hope someone can help me.

***Thanks in advance.***

**THE ACTIVITY**

CadPersonActivity recover the Id in Bundle extras:

```
public class CadPersonActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {
private ActionBar actionBar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private PersonPageAdapter pageAdapter;
private Person person;
private PersonDAO bd;
private Bundle extras;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cad_person);
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        pageAdapter = new PersonPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
        });

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_id)).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_address)).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_phones)).setTabListener(this));

        if (extras.getInt("id") > 0) {
            bd = new PersonDAO(getApplicationContext());
            person = bd.getPerson(extras.getInt("id"));
            callSetFields();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (bd != null)
            bd.close();
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    private void callSetFields() {
        try {
            FragmentPersonId fragId = (FragmentPersonId) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
            fragId.setFields(person);

            FragmentPersonAddress fragEndereco = (FragmentPersonAddress) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_endereco);
            fragEndereco.setFields(person);

            FragmentPersonPhones fragPhones = (FragmentPersonPhones) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_phones);
            fragPhones.setFields(person);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred while trying to open the record.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

CallSetFields is called when a record is clicked and its Id is passed to CadPersonActivity.

The activity_cad_person.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_id"
        android:name="com.fragment.FragmentPersonId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_id" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_address"
        android:name="com.fragment.FragmentPersonAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_address" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_phones"
        android:name="com.fragment.FragmentPersonPhones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_phones" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**THE FRAGMENTS:**

And each fragment have a code like this:

```
public class FragmentPersonId extends Fragment {

    private EditText edtName;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    public void setFields(Pessoa pessoa) {
        try {
            edtName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edtName);
            edtName.setText(person.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error while setting fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some days searching and trying, I have this

- Declare the class Person in CadPersonActivity as public static;
  public static Person person;
- Now, instantiate these EditTexts and call person.getName directly in onCreateView;
  edtName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
  edtName.setText(CadPersonActivity.person.getName());

I can't see this as a good solution, but it's the best I could find.